# Corda State class Participants list significance

Tags: corda

I am working on a cordap which involves 3 parties (Nodes) viz. A, B, C.

There are 2 flows as :

**Flow 1:** A to B Issuance Flow

Value of participants field in State object : listOf(A, B)

**Result :** Latest states are visible in node A and node B

---

**Flow 2:** B to C Transfer Flow

Value of participants field in State object : listOf(B, C)

**Result :**

1. Latest states are visible in node B & node C
2. No State in Node A is visible. :-( (Node A should show its state which was acquired in Flow 1. Shouldn't it ?)

---

My question is, even if party A is not involved in Flow 2, how did the ledger updates happen on node A and why its states are not visible ?

**Note:**
To get the state, I am running below command on each respective node :

```
run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.example.Mystate
```

Comment: when you are running the query on Node A you are seeing the Tx of Flow 2, which shouldn't be the  case?.or do you want Node A to see the tx that happened in Flow 2?

Comment: My understanding about corda is, Node A should have its state (acquired in Flow 1) intact after Flow 2 is run. However, the case is when I run query on Node A, no state is shown. And yes, since Node A is not involved in Flow 2, Node A should not see the tx that happened in Flow 2. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @Kid101 Updated the question to have more clarity on the problem I am facing. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node A should no longer have the state if he/she is no longer the participant.

```
the vault will store the state if it is one of the participants
```

https://docs.corda.net/api-states.html#the-vault

The ledger on Node A marks the state as consumed and remove Node A from the participants list. Only identities in the participants list should have the unconsumed state on the their ledger/database.

States and Transactions are different. Node A should still have the historical transaction intact from Flow 1. But It should not be able to spend/view the latest unconsumed state anymore since the Flow 2 changed the participants.

Comment: Yep. The second transaction will be stored (since it consumes a state that A is a participant of), but the second state will be ignored since it does not involve A.

Comment: @joel This helps. Thanks.